# Add custom CSS to Wordpress Editor MCE dropdown

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg

I've been experimenting and added some customization to the Wordpress Editor, but would like to find out how to edit / add the css to how the drop-down selection looks. Currently when an option is selected it has a blue background with black / charcoal text. From what I can tell the css file is located in the wp-includes/css/ location with the file name being editor.min.css

I know it's not best practice to edit that file, so is there a different way to edit the css? I'd like to just change either the background color or the color of the text. See screenshot below..

[image]

Comment: Create your own css file in your theme and loadit in your admin - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/ Overwrite the css you want.